# ng-mousedown currentTarget.css() change

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to change the css of an element but i can't get managed to change it's css.

I have a div

```
<div ng-controller="ToolBoxCtrl" id="toolBox" ng-mousedown="StartDrag($event)" ng-mouseup="StopDrag()" ng-mousemove="DragElement($event)"></div>
```

and this controller code

```
$scope.StartDrag = function(event)
{
    b_draged = true;
    currentTarget = event.currentTarget
}

$scope.DragElement = function(event)
{
    if(b_draged === true)
    {
        angular.element(currentTarget).css("top",event.offsetX);
        angular.element(currentTarget).css("right",event.offsetY);
        var tar = angular.element(currentTarget);
        var right = angular.element(currentTarget).css("right");
        var top = angular.element(currentTarget).css("top");
        console.log(tar+' '+right+' '+top +' '+right2);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't change the css of the element.

A little background to what i want to achieve: I want to create a draggable div.

**EDIT**:

It seems that the ng-mousemove function is never called. Mousedown and mouseup seem to work perfectly

Comment: `currentTarget.style.top = event.offsetX`

Comment: The value of event.offsetX is set but the currentTarget.style.top value seems to be empty, even after it was set.